# App engine email. It says it sends but i dont receive it

Tags: java, spring-boot, email, google-app-engine

Im making a notifications feature to my website. I use app engine mail, and while it logs saying the email was sent, as seen below, i never receive it.
Logs:

```
INFO: MailService.send
abr 25, 2020 6:26:44 PM com.google.appengine.api.mail.dev.LocalMailService log
INFO:   From: noreply@myapp.appspotmail.com
abr 25, 2020 6:26:44 PM com.google.appengine.api.mail.dev.LocalMailService log
INFO:   To: emailTest@gmail.com
abr 25, 2020 6:26:44 PM com.google.appengine.api.mail.dev.LocalMailService log
INFO:   Reply-to: noreply@myapp.appspotmail.com
abr 25, 2020 6:26:44 PM com.google.appengine.api.mail.dev.LocalMailService log
INFO:   Subject: 
abr 25, 2020 6:26:44 PM com.google.appengine.api.mail.dev.LocalMailService log
INFO:   Body:
abr 25, 2020 6:26:44 PM com.google.appengine.api.mail.dev.LocalMailService log
INFO:     Content-type: text/html
abr 25, 2020 6:26:44 PM com.google.appengine.api.mail.dev.LocalMailService log
INFO:     Data length: 2795
```

Here is my java code where i send the email. Im using an html file coming from cloud storage, that is loading. When i log.info(data) it does print out all of the file.

```
public void confirmationEmail(String name, String email, String lang) {
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(new Properties(), null);
        try {
            Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(email("noreply")));
            msg.addRecipient(TO, new InternetAddress(email));
            msg.setSubject(lang.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.Languages.EN) ? CONFIRMATION_EN : CONFIRMATION_PT);
            String data = new String(CloudStorage.getPrivate(String.format("confirmation-%s.html", lang), CloudStorageFolder.SYSTEM), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            data.replace("$name", name);
            Multipart multi = new MimeMultipart();
            MimeBodyPart html = new MimeBodyPart();
            html.setContent(data, "text/html");
            multi.addBodyPart(html);
            msg.setContent(multi);
            log.info(data);
            Transport.send(msg);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[App Engine mail API for Java](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/mail) is deprecated. You should try to use a third-party API such as [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/)

Here is a sample on how to send a mail with SendGrid and Java:

```
import com.sendgrid.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Example {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Email from = new Email("test@example.com");
    String subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun";
    Email to = new Email("test@example.com");
    Content content = new Content("text/plain", "and easy to do anywhere, even with Java");
    Mail mail = new Mail(from, subject, to, content);

    SendGrid sg = new SendGrid(System.getenv("SENDGRID_API_KEY"));
    Request request = new Request();
    try {
      request.setMethod(Method.POST);
      request.setEndpoint("mail/send");
      request.setBody(mail.build());
      Response response = sg.api(request);
      System.out.println(response.getStatusCode());
      System.out.println(response.getBody());
      System.out.println(response.getHeaders());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      throw ex;
    }
  }
}
```

Also **always** check your spam inbox.